# Propositional Logic - Associative Property question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$p \land \lnot q \lor q \land \lnot r \lor \lnot p \lor r $
$\equiv$$(p \lor \lnot p) \land (\lnot q \lor q) \land (\lnot r \lor r)$

Is this move "legal"? Or can you only apply the associative property on like operators?

Comment: Hard to judge about move, since left-hand side is unreadable.

Comment: You are also applying a commutative property at the same time, which makes this even harder to follow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Associativity** applies only when the connectives involved are exclusively $\land$ or exclusively $\lor$:

$$p \land q \land r \equiv (p \land q)\land r \equiv p \land (q\land r)$$

$$p \lor q \lor r \equiv (p \lor q)\lor r \equiv p \lor (q\lor r)$$

Because of associativity of $\lor$ and $\land$, parentheses are not necessary to define expressions like those above.

Your statement, however:

$$p \land \lnot q \lor q \land \lnot r \lor \lnot p \lor r \tag{given}$$

has *mixed connectives*, and so *associativity does not apply* across all possible groupings.

***Please note***: as stated, your (given) expression ***is not well-defined without parentheses***. That is, without parentheses, it is ambiguous; it can be read any number of ways, most of which are not equivalent. Does it mean connect from left to right?:

$$(((((p\land \lnot q) \lor q) \land) \lnot r)\lor\lnot p) \lor r\;?\tag{1}$$

Or does it mean this?

$(p \land \lnot q) \lor (q \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)\;?\tag{2}$

or any number of other possible ways of grouping with parentheses?

---

In general, when you have an expression like $(2)$ above, you need to apply the **Distributive Laws** to distribute *over* another connective:

For example $$p \land (q \lor r) \equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)$$
$$p \lor (q\land r) \equiv (p \lor q) \land (p\lor r)$$

Comment: Does boolean logic have a mathematically defined "order of operations"? Programming languages typically define one (which they call "precedence") for boolean operators, but I'm not certain if this comes from some mathematical definition or not.

Comment: In theory, there is an order of precendence defined, but I have seen at least two different, mutually contradictory versions of it (one rates $\vee$ higher, the other $\wedge$).

Comment: Associativity, by itself, is NOT sufficient for defining expressions like p^(q^r) where the rule of replacement is NOT restricted, and the structure in question has more than one operation.  If you have the rule of replacement, and you deal with ({0, 1}, ^) as a structure, then you can drop all parentheses.  But, if you deal with ({0, 1}, ^, v), and you drop parentheses as liberally as you want, then 1^(0v0) is ambiguous, since from 0v0=0 we can derive 1^(0v0)=1^0=0, and since it is true that 1=1v0, it would come as valid to derive that 1^(0v0)=1v0^(0v0)=1v(0^(0v0))=1v0=1.

Comment: @amWhy: Lovely answer +1

Comment: Just logged in to upvote. Very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, mixed expressions like this are not associative; instead, they obey distributive laws:
$$
(a\wedge b)\vee c \equiv (a\vee c) \wedge (b \vee c)
$$
and
$$
a \wedge (b\vee c) \equiv(a\wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c).
$$